# Class deciding having problems

Tags: java, class

Consider a program for keeping, and reporting about, information about bowlers and teams in a bowling club.  Every week there is a tournament. Each player, in teams of 4, bowls 3 games. Teams accumulate points according to how many teams they beat in tournaments, and players' averages are tracked. Make a list of classes and class responsibilities.

What is the best way about going at this?

These are the classes I have so far:

- `BowlerNames` creates an array that stores the bowlers names in it
- `Teams` takes the names from the array in BowlerNames and puts them into teams
- `TeamScore` initiates the object TeamScore and player score
- `Game` Records bowlers scores during a game
- `points` takes the score of players during their games and adds it to their team score
- `TeamWin` initiates a wins object, if a team’s points are bigger than the other team it adds one to the wins object
- `Average` takes a players score object and finds its average

Comment: what text book is that question out of?

Comment: Pen & paper, some brain activity and a first idea would be cool (Who = class, does what = responsibility). We won't do your assignments for you... in particular if you don't show any sign of effort so, please, give it some tought first and then try again.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? Then think yourself, Write down "what or who" is participating at that description and make a class for each one.

Comment: fixed it forgot to show what i have so far

Comment: I would go back to basics. Forget about Java, forget about classes. Write down everything that happens in the bowling club. Identify what activities are being carried out and by whom. That will help you build an accurate mental model of the world you need to represent. Then you can start turning this model into classes.

Comment: That is what I'm in the process of doing but i am extremely busy and being overwhelmed by work.

Comment: There's not much we can do then, is there. We can't do your assignment for you and we can't do your other work either. You need to go through the process, there's no other way of learning. With practice it will become second nature and won't take up much of your time that's all I can say to cheer you up.

Answer (score 2):

Some advice, just because you can it doesn't mean everything has to be a class. Some things like, for example, the team's score are information about someone or something. Those, rather than a class, are fields.

When do you need a class? When you have an entity, an object, someone you want to represent in your code. A person, a car, an item, those are classic examples of classes.

You have to find the relationship between the different things you're going to write code about, and give them the behaviour they shoould have, by writing the ideas that come to mind. For example:

- Players *are grouped* in teams
- Players *have* an average score
- Teams *participate* in games
- Teams *accumulate* scores
- All the information *is managed* by the program

There are several other ideas you can come up with, but whenever you do try to learn to identify the pattern behind them. Actions ussualy represent responsibilities that range from management to just "know" something. Subjects are usually classes, unless you're talking about some higher-level functionality. In those cases, you have particular classes that manage the information.

I'll spill out some beans here, but you seem to need a starting ground, not to do it for you but to shed some light as to how should you approach a problem. Approaching first, solving later.

`TeamScore` is rather useless. As its name says, it is a `Team`'s score so, in fact, it's a `Team`'s attribute rather than an object itself since it will only hold the actual score. How do you calculate averages and how do you add scores is up to you, just remember that you're programming a little app

> for keeping, and reporting about, information (...)